# how to move all commits from a particular commit to new branch

Tags: git, version-control

By mistake, I made several commits to the master branch. Now I want to clean up the master branch and move all commits from it to an entirely new branch. How do I do that? I found few similar questions but none seemed to move all the following commit. I did the following

```
git checkout -b bulk-work <hash of the first commit I made>
```

I was expecting this to move all commits after the first commit to move to new branch. Instead it moved the particular commit and its parent to new commit. How do I do the reverse i.e. move the first commit and all commits after that to a new branch?

Comment: That's what `git rebase` does, moves commit to a branch.

Comment: git rebase will move the history of one branch into the history of a second branch that already exists. I believe the OP just wants to move all the commits of the master branch into a new branch (git branch bulk-work) and then rollback the master branch to the point where he/she made the accidental commits to the master branch (git reset --hard <hash>). If this is the correct understanding, then my solution below will work.

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if it worked for you, Shijan Shrestha. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do correctly, I would do this:

```
git checkout -b bulk-work
```

Like you sort of had there; this essentially makes a copy of all of the master branch. Then I would do this:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard <the hash of a commit to reset to>
```

This makes it so that your master branch rewinds all the way to whatever hash you put in the '<>'.

---

I think to simplify this by the way you can just do this:

```
git branch bulk-work
git reset --hard <hash>
```

Since the very first command I did makes a new branch and checks it out.

---

After doing those, make sure to checkout your bulk-work branch to continue working until you're ready to merge, and I assume you know from there.

Comment: That worked! thank you very much. Could you also upvote the question. This I think is a common enough scenario that others might find useful.